# How to implement Android TV module in already existing app in production?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-build, android-tv

I've got an app on the Play Store that's already live. I developed an Android TV module for it, and I took out some code in a core module to share it between the tv and app modules. Now when I try to export an apk it always asks me if I want to do it for the app or the tv module.
How should I do? I'm afraid that if I build the TV apk it will override my app one that's already live. Am I completely wrong? Is there a way to make an apk that includes everything or is it correct to have two? And if having two is correct, how should I implement it live without losing the one that includes the app that's already live?

Comment: You may want to check this [Distribute to Android TV](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-tv.html) documentation. To get started, review this page to learn how to distribute your TV apps to users through Google Play. Be sure to read [TV app quality](https://developer.android.com/develop/quality-guidelines/tv-app-quality.html) for information on the usability and quality standards that your apps should meet. When your app is ready, you can opt-in to publishing in the Android TV storefront from the Google Play Console.

Comment: I've already read everything in the links you provided. Nothing is mentioned about what I asked. I've found something in the [Multiple APK Support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) page, but not really specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can have multiple APKs for apps. When you upload your update you are given the option to retain an older APK version if you would like. This option appears when you select "review" for your new APK. So you could have one APK for tv while the other is for mobile devices. As long as the update is the going to be the highest version you will be fine. It doesn't matter if the tv or mobile app is higher or if they keep switching on which is higher.